# Samsung device shows two IMEI numbers what is purpose of this two?

Tags: imei

Press  *#06#  Samsung device shows two IMEI numbers what is purpose of this two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the phone is dual-SIM then it has two modems (maybe one in practice, which is registrered to two networks) and thus two registrations to network. For each registration a unique IMEI is needed.
Cheers :)

Comment: Thank u very much for valuable respone